# how can i delete .svn directories and "entries" files on an old subversion source codebase

Tags: windows-xp, svn

i have a windows xp machine and i am trying to delete a directory with some old source code that was once hooked up to subversion but the repository is no longer there.

when i  try to delete the directory i get this error:

[image]

i see that the directory is read only but when i try to remove the read only flag, it pops up this screen:

[image]

but then fails with the following error:

[image]

i have tried using unlocker and a few other tools but nothing will allow me to delete this directory.

i do have admin rights on the machine.  Is there any recommendation for something that can brute force delete a directory even given the above issues.  I am not sure if this is subversion not allowing the deletion or its something in windows xp directly.

### Update

It seems now that i can delete individual files in a directory but can't delete any directories or any bulk directory sub directory delete.

as mentioned, unlocker does pop up but says that no other process has no handle locking the files

[image]

also, i disabled Simple file sharing and took ownership of the folders (i was not originally) and then tried the steps above but still getting the same access denied errors.

Comment: Try and kill TSVNCache.exe in task manager, then delete the dir. Assuming you have rebooted, etc...?

Comment: @Aaron - even killing TSNVCache.exe still has the issue. as mentioned, i have unlocker and that doesn't see anyone locking the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try taking ownership of the folder following these [steps](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421). It appears it may have something to do with permissions/security since Unlocker is not recognizing any locks on the files/folders.

Comment: @Aaron - even after taking ownership of the folder, i still and getting the same errors after trying to delete the folder / files

Comment: @ooo You took ownership then gave yourself privs?

Comment: @Aaron - yes.  it seems the issue is trying to delete the .svn folders and the "entries" svn file.  Still getting access denied on these

Comment: @ooo Ok, so only on svn dirs...this may sound strange, but have you uninstalled your SVN client, rebooted and then attempt to delete?

Comment: @Aaron - i completely uninstalled tortoise and then rebooted and still having issues deleting the entries and the .svn directories

Comment: @ooo The last thing I can think to try is to attempt to delete the offenders via cmd, as this had positive effects if I recall pre-Windows XP days...del blah.txt

Comment: @Aaron - getting access denied in cmd mode as well :(

Comment: @ooo So what happens when you delete from within Unlocker...forgot to ask that...

Comment: @Aaron - unfortunately nothing seems to happen.  no error but nothing gets deleted

Answer (score 0):

This likely means that the file is locked by some other process.

One way to find this out is to use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), and use the Find Handle Or DLL function to find out which process has a lock on the `entries` file.  I'm sure there are other utilities that will perform the same functionality.

Once you know what process has locked the file, close that process (or cause it to relinquish the lock) and try again.

As a total guess, I would suggest that if you're using Tortoise SVN, the `TSNVCache.exe` process is the one locking the file.

Comment: He mentioned the use of Unlocker, which looks for locks and unlocks them as needed.

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle - even killing TSNVCache.exe still has the issue.  as mentioned, i have unlocker and that doesn't see anyone locking the file